# dotnet-core-uninstall doesn't see some versions

Tags: .net, .net-core

As I began to pickup a legacy project at work, I ran into some version collision issues with .net sdks and decided to uninstall all my .net sdks(start from scratch). Upon doing this I had 3 versions:

- 6.0.302
- 6.0.308
- 7.0.100

I used `<Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features>` to remove dotnet 6 and dotnet 7. But I still saw the 6.9.302 was still being listed. I checked my files and it is still there:

[image]

After searching through the microsoft docs, it was suggested to download the uninstall commandline tool. I did that and am having the following experience where the tool does not see the installed version:

[image]

I would prefer to use a proper uninstaller instead of just deleting the folders in my program files and removing it from my environment variables, as the uninstaller should also remove lingering services, registry edit files, and other lingering files throughout the system (remember I want a clean start).

Any ideas?